# Consistent periodic first-chance SocketException in AWS ECS/Fargate hosted Asp.NET web service

Tags: asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs

I have a Asp.NET Core 5 web service (.NET 5) hosted in AWS ECS/Fargate.  It uses an Application Load Balancer (ALB) with health checks enabled pointing to `/health` which uses the standard [health checks library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

I'm monitoring the service with Datadog and with [dotnet runtime metrics](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/runtime_metrics/dotnet/) turned on.  With this monitoring, we are seeing a consistent ~30 first-chance SocketException(s) per minute.  Even when sitting idle and not handling any *real* requests.  The only requests being served are the health check requests.

I remote exec'd into the ECS task and used `dotnet-dump` to get the exception from the heap of a memory dump.  Here's what I found:

```
Exception type:   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message:          Operation canceled
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.<GetResult>g__ThrowSocketException|7_0(System.Net.Sockets.SocketError)+0x2a
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketAwaitableEventArgs.GetResult()+0x29
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection+<ProcessReceives>d__28.MoveNext()+0x1b5
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()+0x1c
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0xcc
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0x46
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection+<DoReceive>d__27.MoveNext()+0xfb
```

We have a less regular first-chance ObjectDisposedException (~1 per minute) that could also be related (or a race condition artifact of the other).  Which I found in the memory dump analysis:

```
Exception type:   System.ObjectDisposedException
Message:          Cannot access a disposed object.
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ThrowObjectDisposedException()+0x6a
    System.Net.Sockets.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveAsync(System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs, System.Threading.CancellationToken)+0x67
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection+<ProcessReceives>d__28.MoveNext()+0x219
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()+0x1c
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0xcc
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)+0x46
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.Internal.SocketConnection+<DoReceive>d__27.MoveNext()+0xfb
```

I don't see this issue when running on my local machine.  And I do not see any logs that indicate that any requests were cancelled.

I suspected that ALB was not reading the response body and cancelling every request after reading only the status code.  So I changed the health check `HealthCheckOptions.ResponseWriter` to return 204-NoContent with no response body, but that didn't help at all.

Comment: Can you show more details about the code before the socket is closed ? Be careful to hide confidential information.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to show.  The stack traces are all related to AspNetCore Kestrel.  I could show some of the code for the health checks, but that's only a hunch and might not be relevant.

Comment: I found same exceptions (SocketException, HttpRequestException, IOException, ObjectDisposeException) on DD .Net Runtime Metrics.
I'm already investigating, so I hope we can find the source of them soon.